# Alternative to Google Apps Admin Settings API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, single-sign-on, google-admin-settings-api

The Admin Settings API is deprecated and is scheduled to be sunset on August 16, 2017. I have used this API's in our application to enable/disable Single Sign On. Is there any alternative to the Google Apps Admin Settings API.

I have referred below link.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/

Here is the code I'm using to enable Single Sign On (SSO).

```
try{

    Collection<String> SCOPES = new ArrayList<String>();
    SCOPES.add("https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/");
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
    .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
    .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
    .setServiceAccountUser(ADMIN_EMAIL)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
            new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
            .build();
    //Sets the Single Sign On settings and Uploads the public key.
    SingleSignOnService ssoservice = new SingleSignOnService(DOMAIN_NAME,APPLICATION_NAME);
    ssoservice.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);

    final String key = SECRET_KEY;

    GenericEntry update = new GenericEntry();
    update.addProperty("samlSignonUri",SAML_SIGNON_URL);
    update.addProperty("samlLogoutUri", SAML_LOGOUT_URL);

    update.addProperty("changePasswordUri",CHANGE_PASSWORD_URL);

    update.addProperty("enableSSO", "true");
    update.addProperty("ssoWhitelist", "");
    update.addProperty("useDomainSpecificIssuer", "false");

    ssoservice.updateSSOSettings(update);
    ssoservice.updateSsoSigningKey(key);

    response.sendRedirect(callBackUrl);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    ErrorHandler.errorHandler(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),e);
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: The old version of the API will be deprecated (the one that is running on `GData`). The newest Json API will not have any modification. [Goodbye to GData Admin](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.it/2016/08/saying-goodbye-to-gdata-admin-settings.html)